# How to access public_html via FileZilla?

Tags: ftp, sftp, cpanel, filezilla, public-html

Our website is hosted using CPanel. When we connect over sftp via FileZilla, for some reason, we're unable to access `public_html`. It works with FileZilla on the mac but on the PC, if we type in the same directory, it automatically adds a backslash, so it becomes `public_html\`, which doesn't work for displaying the site.

What would you suggest to connect to `public_html` without the backslash?

Answer (score -1):

you have to type in ../ under remote site and press enter.

it'll take you to the root. You should be able to enter any path.